# How to stop header showing up in nomenclature page?

Tags: header-footer, nomenclature

I am trying to make a nomenclature table but the header seems to keep showing up at the top of the page?

```
\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\cleardoublepage           
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols} %% may be this is good.
\markboth{\MakeUppercase\nomname}{\MakeUppercase\nomname} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\nomenclature{$a$}{action}

\printnomenclature
```

Comment: Maybe  `\thispagestyle{empty}` just after `\cleardoublepage`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can precise it is a backmatter section as follow :

```
\backmatter
\tableofcontents
```